# Printing up to 100th column

Tags: vim

My way of *writing stuff* looks something like this - I have a `colorcolumn` in Vim set on 100. The actual stuff that will get printed and go in the manual goes into the text that is before the 100th column, and my notes, comments, ... stuff that should not be seen, or that isn't relevant to the current version goes afterwards the 100th column.

It is an amazingly simple and effective system.

So, here's my question ... ***how can I print (into PDF) everything up to 100th column, disregarding anything after it?***

I was thinking of a system: move everything into a temporary file, delete everything after the 100th column, print the remaining *stuff* ... but is there a way to make this really quick, like put it into one command/function, so I don't have to step through five different steps along the way?

All constructive ideas welcomed ...

Comment: You could make a function of it. Not *too* hard to put it into another buffer and save that. (If you don't mind using Python, it could be done more easily still.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - No, I got python support installed. Could you put up a draft version if you have a specific approach on your mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have a pdf printer (e.g. `cups-pdf` installed you can do something like:

1. `:set pdev=pdf`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. `:set printoptions=paper:A4,syntax:y,wrap:y`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. `:%s:^\(.\{100\}\).*:\1:`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
4. `:hardcopy`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. <kbd>u</kbd>

I'm leaving it to you to create a function/command from it.

Comment: Very nice ... the pdev option was what I was really looking for. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `vim`?

```
:%s/.*/\=getline('.')[:100]/
```

Comment: Uhmm, in Vim, yes. Anyways, you know a way maybe how to automate the whole process - putting the results of (the above) into a text file (filename.prn or something), and then printing it out at the same time?